# why this not working site:moneycontrol "Reliance"?

Tags: python-3.x

Reliance has new on today
why it is not giving any results?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='E:/materials/AI/github/Sentiment-analysis-of-financial-news-data-master/code/chromedriver.exe')
```

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

```
(tensorflow) E:\materials\AI\github\Sentiment-analysis-of-financial-news-data-master\code>python search_scrape.py
```

## Enter the details to scrape separated by SPACE.

Enter starting day month year 1 1 2019
Enter ending day month year 8 1 2019
Enter website to scrape- moneycontrol
Enter company data to scrape -Reliance

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:10544/devtools/browser/2da58522-de69-4c9d-b705-30d3104bbaf0
0
Message:

********Finished fetching all the urls********

##Fetched 0

Comment: why its not working?

Comment: can you share the complete code snippet and what you're trying to achieve here? Above code says that you're creating a chrome webdriver

Comment: its work when we gives space to search                           site: Moneycontrol " HFCL"

Comment: Use of chrome driver